why does LASSO regression return unstandardized coefficients
I have more general questions that does not refer to a coding issue.
Why does LASSO regression require standardization of the predictors but return unstandardized coefficients (glmnet function - https://glmnet.stanford.edu/reference/glmnet.html#:~:text=Logical%20flag%20for%20x%20variable%20standardization%2C%20prior%20to,returned%20on%20the%20original%20scale.%20Default%20is%20standardize%3DTRUE.)?

Lasso regression does not require standardisation of the predictors: the help page you linked to describes an option for glmnet to standardise or not.  I assume the coefficients are returned on the original scale because that's the scale of the X that you supplied and so presumptively the scale you are interested in.
The reason standardisation matters for the lasso and not for glm is that the penalty function in lasso is on the scale of the $\beta$s and separate from the Xs.
In an ordinary linear or generalised linear model, standardisation doesn't really matter: if you multiply an $X$ by two the corresponding $\beta$ will be divided by two and there's no effect on the model.   In lasso if you multiply an $X$ by two and divide the corresponding $\beta$ by two the deviance part of the objective function stays the same but the penalty part changes, and you get a different fitted model (one that penalises that particular variable half as much).
So, the scales of the Xs matter for lasso in a way that they don't for lm and glm.  You can either choose the scales yourself -- as the linked help page says, leaving them unchanged  might make sense if the Xs are all in the same units  -- or you can do a crude standardisation to make them all have the same variance.

Is it correct to say there's no way to conduct a valid hypothesis test comparing GLM and LASSO coefficients? Or is there some dark magic?

I wouldn't go as far as saying there's no way. I don't know a way, though,

Coming back to @dimitiy's question: actually, what even would the null hypothesis be? The estimated coefficients are not the same, and the true (population or model) coefficients are the same.

The OP wanted to test the null of equality between unstandardized penalized and unpenalized coefficients, but that part of the question was edited out.

Yes, I remember. That's the question where I don't think the null hypothesis makes any sense.
